# How can I compute formal power series for ratio of functions in SymPy? [AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'truncate']

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use the SymPy [formal power series](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/formal.html) feature but am running into attribute errors.

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.abc import x
sy.fps(x / (1 - sy.exp(-x))).truncate()
```

But I get

```
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'truncate'
```

I had read about namespace issues with NumPy so tried to specify the exponential function for SymPy but it didn't work.  I'm just trying to compute the Taylor series expansion of

```
x / (1 - exp(-x))
```

and various powers of it, e.g.

```
(x / (1 - exp(-x)))**8
```

The fps function works fine until I try to divide analytic funcions.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to compute the Taylor series expansion, perhaps [sympy.series](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/series.html#sympy.series.series.series) is what you're after?

**Example:**

```
from sympy import series, symbols, exp
from pprint import pprint
x = symbols("x")
pprint(series(x / (1 - exp(-x))))
pprint(series((x / (1 - exp(-x)))**8))
```

**Output:**

```
1 + x/2 + x**2/12 - x**4/720 + O(x**6)
1 + 4*x + 23*x**2/3 + 28*x**3/3 + 967*x**4/120 + 469*x**5/90 + O(x**6)
```